# The kinetic energy of a proton when it enters and exits a magnetic field created by a solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Does the kinetic energy vary? The problem gives me the velocity and the mass, so I can calculate the kinetic energy with the formula: k=1/2mv^2

As it doesn't give me its first kinetic energy or its last I'm supposing that it doesn't change. Correct me if I' wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic force that a charge experiences is always perpendicular to the velocity of the charge instantaneously. This can be seen by this equation. $$ F=v\times B q $$  Since the work done by a force is displacement in the direction of force, work done by magnetic force will by zero. Hence the energy won't change until a force other than magnetic force is applied.
Note that it doesn't matter whether the field is created by a solenoid or by a wire.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late I've been really busy. I think I get it now. So I would calculate the kinetic energy with the formula that I wrote in the description, right?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{|d (KE)|}{dt}=|\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}|=|(q\vec{v}\times \vec{B})\cdot \vec{v}|=0$

Rate of change of kinetic energy is equal to the dot product of force with velocity. By the Lorentz' force law, $\vec{F}=(q\vec{v}\times \vec{B})$.

So the force is orthogonal to velocity. The scalar product of orthogonal vectors is zero.

How much work is done lifting a car from the ground to 3 meters above it?

What if this action is performed by an electromagnet?

Does this conflict with the above analysis?